# Не работает анимация в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, анимация

Работая с Unity, столкнулся с проблемой - не могу никак создать анимацию персонажа и привязать её к кнопкам. В чём **суть проблемы** - Я создал четырёх кадровые клипы для движения персонажа во все стороны? создавал из четырёх картинок в стандартном "Animation". Теперь хочу привязать клипы к кнопкам.

Код:

```
public class Anim : MonoBehaviour {
    Animator _anim;

    void Start() {
        _anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Update() {
        if(Input.GetKey(Keycode.A)){
            _anim.SetInteger("State", 3);
        }
        else {
            _anim.SetInteger("State", 5);
        }
        if(Input.GetKey(Keycode.D)){
            _anim.SetInteger("State", 4);
        }
        else {
            _anim.SetInteger("State", 5);
        }
        if(Input.GetKey(Keycode.W)){
            _anim.SetInteger("State", 1);
        }
        else {
            _anim.SetInteger("State", 5);
        }
        if(Input.GetKey(Keycode.S)){
            _anim.SetInteger("State", 2);
        }
        else {
            _anim.SetInteger("State", 5);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Такую ошибку выдаёт]

[image: Схема]

Comment: а код увидеть можно?

Comment: Было довольно много скриптов, но я их уже удалил. Насколько помню, было через команду (точное название сейчас не вспомню) "запустить клип с таким-то именем". Сейчас вот писал через данные команды присваивая переходу между анимациями индекс

Comment: using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Anim : MonoBehaviour {
    Animator _anim;
 void start()
    {
        _anim = GetComponent<Animator>(); 
    }
 
 void Update () {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
           _anim.SetInteger("State", 4);
                    }
        else

Comment: Добавьте код в вопрос, а не в комментарии.

Comment: Добавил, вроде как

Comment: Добавьте скриншот настройки стейт машины анимаций

Comment: Добавил. Это то что нужно?

Comment: ... и метод Start должен писаться с большой буквы, что бы в Юнити его вызов сработал при создании объекта.

Comment: Да, ошибка в `start()`, нужно писать с заглавной буквы. В данном случае компонент не линкуется и вы получаете null reference exception.

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский, оформите свой комментарий как ответ, вы, как никак, первый увидели ошибку :)

Comment: Секунду, да - старт не досмотрел, но ничего так и не проигрывается

Comment: Ошибка исчезла, а анимации как не было так и нет

Comment: Добавьте скриншот свойств стейт машины, вы уверены, что вы добавили туда `"State"` как поле `int` и сделали условие перехода анимации от этого св-ва?

Comment: не совсем понимаю, что именно должен скринить, но добавлял да - как int. В вопрос добавил скрипт полный, сейчас с ним работает только анимация "MoveDown". Хотя у неё все настройки такие же как и других

Comment: Вы неправильно составили код, самое последнее условие отвечает за MoveDown, судя по клавише. Проблема в том, что оператор else в самом конце будет срабатывать всегда, кроме ситуации с нажатой клавишей "S".

Comment: Подскажите, что переписать. Я сам не вижу, к сожалению. Сейчас протыкал каждый "else". Показывает, что каждый из них связан со своим "if". Ещё и "{ }" везде расставил . Вроде как всё верно.

Comment: Чтобы уж совсем все хорошо было - вставьте в ваш вопрос код, а не скриншот кода, так уж у нас принято здесь :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вся проблема в том, что каждый следующий if-else поменяет значение свойства "State" в конечном автомате аниматора.

Решение простое - нужно сделать общий else, который будет отрабатывать, если никакая клавиша не нажата. Более того, поскольку в каждый отдельный момент времени автомат имеет только одно состояние, если смысл связать все if'ы с помощью `if-else if`'ов.

Верный код со всеми правками:

```
public class Anim : MonoBehaviour {
    Animator _anim;

    void Start() {
        _anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Update() {
        if(Input.GetKey(Keycode.A)){
            _anim.SetInteger("State", 3);
        }
        else if(Input.GetKey(Keycode.D)){
            _anim.SetInteger("State", 4);
        }
        else if(Input.GetKey(Keycode.W)){
            _anim.SetInteger("State", 1);
        }
        else if(Input.GetKey(Keycode.S)){
            _anim.SetInteger("State", 2);
        }
        else {
            _anim.SetInteger("State", 5);
        }
    }
}
```

Ситуация с отдельными if'ами будет работать, но такой подход сохранит вам пару проверок условий :)

Comment: Спасибо Вам за помощь! В вопросе скинул скрипт, который написал до того, как увидел Ваш ответ, но данный Вами скрипт мне больше по душе. Ещё раз огромное спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @Vasiliy верные ответы тут принято отмечать "верным ответом". И лучше удалите ваш новый код - он будет только глаза новичкам мозолить :)

Comment: Удалил, отметил. Впервые на этом форуме, так что - прошу прощения за некоторое невежество. В очередной раз благодарю за оказанную помощь :)

Comment: @Vasiliy, да ничего страшного, со всеми бывает)